# Check Bitcoin Balance with mybitx api https GET url

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

I am new to integrating bitcoin API to my PHP page, I have created a bitcoin account with luno, I have created API Key.

I have been given this url to get balance using my generated API Key:

```
$ curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
```

Can anybody help with a proper example on how I can use my API with this given url to display my wallet balance on a PHP page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way I know to convert `curl` commands to executable PHP code is to use this site: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Just add your `curl` command:

```
curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
```

to the textbox that says "Paste curl here". Then take the PHP that is output and integrate it into your app.

Comment: this worked just perfectly, although I did not use the actual key in the form, I added it when I copied out the finished php. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [PHP Requests library](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) for an easy way to make HTTP Requests. Your `curl` command can be converted as follows:

```
<?php
    include('vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php');
    Requests::register_autoloader();
    // Use additional headers if necessary
    $headers = array();
    // Create authorization using key and secret.
    $options = array('auth' => array('keyid', 'keysecret'));
    // Create the GET request to the URL
    $response = Requests::get('https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance', $headers, $options);
    // The result is available in $response
?>
```